# Difference between allusion and connotation (in english literature)

Tags: literature

I am not sure if it's just my imagination (because I can't find any comparison of the terms in literary theory dictionaries) but these seem very close terms?

Can you explain any overlap and differences?

Comment: Have you looked them up in a good dictionary?

Comment: In a Lit Crit context, an *allusion* normally means the author deliberately intended to put the reader in mind of [whatever he's alluding to]. But a *connotation* may be entirely accidental/unconscious (feasibly, even something which *could not have been known* at the original time of writing, but which affects later generations of readers).

Comment: @WS2 sure but they seem close

Comment: @FumbleFingers would you agree that connotation is a polysemous allusion (i.e. alluding not to one specific use)?

Comment: @user3293056: No, I wouldn't. *Polysemy* is usually an inherent quality of a specific *word* (or phrase), where we use *context* to "screen out" the "unwanted" meanings (often without even noticing). But *literary connotations* can involve meanings far removed from any of the actual individual words and phrases in the text - all that matters is that you the reader are somehow put in mind of things that go beyond the overt references.

Comment: this is actually a very popular (closed) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allusion is when in language you make a reference to another work of art, or element of culture. For example, if a writer wrote "Yada Yada" in his book, it'd be an allusion to Seinfeld.

Connotation means something different entirely.  It is the meaning beyond the literal meaning. The best illustration I can make is a negative/positive one: calling someone "childlike" has a negative connotation.  Calling that same person "youthful" would have a positive connotation. They have the same literal meanings.

There is not much overlap between the terms.

**In short: An allusion almost certainly refers to something very specific. A connotation is not specific in any way. Knowing that calling someone "childlike" is negative comes only from knowing the deeper meaning of words. It's non-specific**

Comment: I disagree that first paragraph. Google Books claims over 5000 written instances of [*allusions to slavery*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22allusions+to+slavery%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), and although I'd be happy to refer to a slaver as a "piece of work", I wouldn't call what he does "a work of art".

Comment: I used "work of art" for lack of a better term.  I'm not sure what phrase you'd suggest instead.

Comment: i think that's kinda it... allusion is reference to something more concrete than connote  ???

Comment: Allusion, is non-explicit reference.  A connotation is a non-obvious, non-literal meaning--but still a meaning that one could (maybe would) draw from the word.

Comment: OK so the difference is that allusion requires more than familiarity with the language but also its literature ?

Comment: An allusion almost certainly refers to something very specific.  A connotation is not specific in any way.  Knowing that calling someone "childlike" is negative comes only from knowing the deeper meaning of words.  It's non-specific.

Comment: good answer thanks - maybe you should update your answer with that and i can accept it ?

Comment: I have looked in the OED and in the Oxford Dictionary Online and I can find nothing which suggests that *connotation* cannot be to something specific. I don't know where the idea has come from that *connote* has to be toward something non-specific, but perhaps you could enlighten us. Your answer provides no reference to any linguistic authority, such as OED or Merriam Webster etc. I would agree that the terms *positive connotation* and *negative connotation* are frequently used, especially by people who think in monochrome, but that tells us nothing.

Comment: @Matthew: I realise now that perhaps you could class something like, say, *slavery* as an *element of culture*. But per my comment to the question itself, I see the primary distinction as being that ***allusions*** are normally references deliberately implied by a writer. Sometimes they're things that only conscientious and aware readers will pick up on, especially if the work is very old and social context has changed a lot. On the other hand, ***connotations*** are normally understood by the majority of [current] readers, even if they're accidental or didn't exist at all at time of writing.

Answer (score 1):

To me an "allusion" is a direct mild comparison communicated by the writer or subject of the sentence.

A "connotation" on the other is an inference that a reader draws from the context of the sentence.

*The girl gazed at the rabbit in childlike innocence*

*The supervisor saw his approach to the problem as childlike rather than pragmatic*

The use of the word "childlike" is positive in the first case and negative in the second. You draw this connotation from the reading of the sentence.

Allusions are referenced in the sentence itself. You are directed to the comparison. The comparison may or may not include the word "allusion"

*His Achilles’ heel was his inability to compromise*

Here the writer directs the reader to think of the Greek hero's weakness when referring to that of the subject of the sentence.

As a verb in a sentence, "allude" could be used this way.

*The magician alluded to Houdini in his preamble to the next escape.*

Again, the writer is making a direct reference. You do not draw any inference from the sentence.

Comment: that's an ok answer but i think you over-emphasized how direct an allusion is, to make ur point

Comment: +1 purely for the first two sentences, which I think succinctly summarise the key elements that distinguish allusions from connotations. The rest could be so much "yada yada" so far as I'm concerned - this is the only one of four answers so far that makes what I see as an unassailable assertion.

Answer (score 0):

allusion: is **indirect, just touched upon** and not forceful

connotation: is **in parallel with** a main meaning

Comment: but what is indirect is in some senses merely parallel - rather than identical i mean

Answer (score 0):

Allusion is refered to some historical fact, political process, mythology, ledgends. Something that will help you understand the story better if you know the meaning of this allusion.

Ex. "Those were the years of Depression." (You are supposed to know when was it, right? This is like the background knowledge.)